# Webscraper doesn't get text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the status (paused or not) of a specific publication, but the text doesn't seem to show up and I don't know how to get it

I currently have this code, which works for other elements of the same page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get("https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-610621665-camara-web-hp-spare-431392-001-y-446486-001-_JM")
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
status=soup.find("p",{"class":"item-status-notification__title"}).text
print(status)
```

What I want to get is this specific status ("publicación pausada" translates to "paused publication"):

[image]

Which, inspecting the element, is stored under a **p class item-status-notification__title**

[image]

but when I tell BS to extract its text, it returns blank spaces

What's wrong with this approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the first match of p with that class but what you want to extract it the 3rd one so you need to use better selector :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get("https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-610621665-camara-web-hp-spare-431392-001-y-446486-001-_JM")
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
status=soup.select_one('section[class="item-status bg-alt"] p.item-status-notification__title').text.strip()

print(status)
```